# Convert from file system path to S3 key?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to create some S3 objects using files in a directory tree. There are spaces and some special characters in the directory and file names.

Is it a built-in boto3 function to convert the full path of a file to S3 key?

Comment: No. There is no such method.

Comment: Be aware of [Object key naming guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html#object-key-guidelines) when you map from local filepaths to S3 keys. You might also want to see what the awscli does - use `aws s3 sync` to sync your local folder tree to S3 and see what it does with whitespace and special characters.